# Paypal IPN working with Simulator but not with Sandbox - C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, webforms, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to implement an IPN-Listener for Confirming Paypal-Payments of my Customers. I tried to implement an IPN-Listener and when I tested it with the Paypal simulator it says verified handshake. Nevertheless when I try to buy something with a sandbox account, and after the payment its linked to my confirmation site, it always says that the transaction is invalid. Do you guys have an idea?

Here is my listener code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Confirmation : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Post back to either sandbox or live
        string strSandbox = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        string strLive = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strSandbox);

        // Set values for the request back
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        byte[] Param = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
        string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Param);
        strRequest = strRequest + "&cmd=_notify-validate";
        req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

        // for proxy
        // Dim proxy As New WebProxy(New System.Uri("http://url:port#"))
        // req.Proxy = proxy

        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;

        // Send the request to PayPal and get the response
        StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
        streamOut.Write(strRequest);
        streamOut.Close();



        StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
        streamIn.Close();

        if (strResponse == "VERIFIED")
        {
            test.InnerText = "Verified";
        }
        else if (strResponse == "INVALID")
        {
            test.InnerText = "invalid";
        }
        else
        {
            test.InnerText = "error";
        }

        Span1.InnerText = strRequest;
        test.InnerText = strResponse;
    }



}
```

EDIT: In the IPN history I get the 200 HTTP Response and its says its verified. But why my code says its INVALID?

Comment: I have implemented IPN integration on a few sites and never seemed to have got the sandbox working when switching to it...I have always just tested on live.. you could add a custom field to indicate a test transaction and ignore it on production.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your help. Unfortunately its not working with a custom value either. I implemented a custom field in the button form and want to get it in the IPN-Listener with "Span2.InnerText = Request.Form["custom"];" but its not working :(